# Incorrect syntax near '('. Expecting ID - no idea how to fix this

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, syntax-error, sql-server-2014

Trying to create a new table from parts of an existing one using:

```
CREATE TABLE Spillover_HE
AS (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Y16_GROW_Teacher]
  WHERE HEDI = 'H');
```

And it keeps returning the error message:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near '('.
```

When I hover over the code it says:

```
Incorrect syntax near '('. Expecting ID.
```

I've tried changing the table name (same error), removing the WHERE statement (that generates an addition error of "Expecting UNION or EXCEPT").  I've read some answers to similar questions but am new to SQL and am very lost.

Comment: I'm guessing from the error style that this is [tag:sql-server]? You should really add a tag for your DBMS. There's no `CREATE TABLE ... AS (SELECT ...` syntax in SQL Server, so far as I'm aware.

Comment: Which platform are you using -- (except db2 as far as I know) let you create a table based on another table like this -- most word it as "SELECT INTO"

Comment: You are looking for the `SELECT .. INTO` or `CREATE TABLE .. LIKE` constructs. Also marking the dbms vendor helps us to answer faster and more precisely.

Comment: SQL Server does not support the standard `create table as ... select`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `SELECT INTO` syntax:

```
SELECT * INTO Spillover_HE
FROM [dbo].[Y16_GROW_Teacher]
WHERE HEDI = 'H'
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work on the MSSQL

```
SELECT * into Spillover_HE FROM [dbo].[Y16_GROW_Teacher] 
  WHERE HEDI = 'H'
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are trying to create view.

```
CREATE VIEW Spillover_HE
AS  (   SELECT  * 
        FROM    [dbo].[Y16_GROW_Teacher]
        WHERE   HEDI = 'H'
    );
```